# How to implement class in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript-generics

Could you help me to create class 'MyClass'
class M should be Newable and implement IMyInterface

```
export interface IMyInterface<A>
{    
    SomeData : A;
}  

export class MyClass<T,M inherits IMyInterface<T> and new() >
{
    list = new Array<M>();

    privete Creator()
    {
        const      obj = new M();
                   obj.SameData = 'Hello data';  
        list.push( obj );
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Think you're looking for something like this...

```js
export interface IMyInterface<A> {
  SomeData: A;
}  

export class MyClass<T, M extends IMyInterface<T>> {
  private list: M[] = [];

  constructor(private constructorFunction: {new(): M; }) {
  }

  public add(item: T): void {
    const obj = new this.constructorFunction();
    obj.SomeData = item;  
    this.list.push(obj);
  }
}

export class MyItem implements IMyInterface<string> {
  public SomeData: string = '';
}

const collection = new MyClass<string, MyItem>(MyItem);
collection.add('Hello data');
```

I've tweaked your psuedocode so that it actually compiles and does what I think you were aiming for in the question. The important thing to note is that the types in TypeScript have no representation at runtime so you can't do `new T()`. Instead you need to pass in the constructor function for your class which has a type of `{ new(): M; }`. You can then do a `new X()` with this value to get an object which extends your interface.